# How to post dynamic 2d array in php server from ionic angularjs and save into mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, multidimensional-array, ionic-framework

I'm getting input from text field dynamically by angularjs

Array format

```
 item[0]['id'] = 0;
 item[1]['text'] = 'abc';
 item[0]['id'] = 1;
 item[1]['text'] = 'xyz';
 .
 .
 .
 item[0]['id'] = n;
 item[1]['text'] = 'zxc';
```

I want to post this array to my php script using angularjs service API

php script should accept this 2d array and save to database.

Comment: What have you tried already? What part isn't working already? We're here to help you understand what needs to be done to solve your problem, not just provide code. The more detailed information you can provide, generally the better your questions is. (The exception being: don't just dump every line you've written into the question.)

Answer (score 0):

For posting the data to your php script you can use Angular's `$http` provider:

```
$http.post('/script.php', item).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Your PHP script will receive these values in the global `$_POST` variable, from there you can process the data and save it to your database.